# Is there a way to transform VueJS template string to createElement syntax

Tags: vue.js, web-component, stenciljs, tsx

I'm working on a wrapper for a web component based on stenciljs from vuejs. I need to be able to pass vuejs component or template string as VNode for my web component.
Is there a way to transform vuejs template string as

`<template><div>My component</div></template>`
to
`createElement('div', 'My component')`
syntax?

Thank you.

#### Updated

From vue docs:

```
// render:
function anonymous() {
  with(this){return _c('div',[_m(0),(message)?_c('p',[_v(_s(message))]):_c('p',[_v("No message.")])])}
}

// staticRenderFns:
_m(0): function anonymous() {
  with(this){return _c('header',[_c('h1',[_v("I'm a template!")])])}
}
```

Comment: It seems like template compilation could be the answer you are looking for: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html If you succeed please update your answer.

Comment: do you mean [render functions](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html)?